# Unable to start service Intent from another app

Tags: android, android-intent, service

I know this question has been a lot of times already, but I tried, I think, all the accepted answers, but it didn't solve my problem. I might be missing something, being new to Services and these kind of intents.

I have two apps, and one of them needs to call a service implemented in the second one.

In my app being called, I declared this in manifest :

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.myapp">

    <application
        android:name=".MyApplication">
        <service
             android:name="com.myapp.SynchronizationService"
             android:exported="true"
             android:enabled="true" >
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

My service being declared as follows :

```java
package com.myapp;

/**
 * Sync service
 */
public class SynchronizationService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        initSync();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private void initSync() {
        //do some work
    }
}
```

And then, in my app calling the service, I have declared this :

```kt
val i = Intent().apply {
    component = ComponentName("com.myapp", "com.myapp.SynchronizationService")
}
val c: ComponentName? = startService(i)
```

And in AndroidManifest.xml :

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.test.intentcaller">
    <application>
        ...
    </application>
    <queries>
        <package android:name="com.myapp" />
    </queries>
</manifest>
```

But when I try to call this, I get this error in logs :

`Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.myapp/.SynchronizationService } U=0: not found`

Thanks

Comment: On which android version you are checking ? Also do u have `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` permission in manifest as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility) ?

Comment: I didn't add `QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES` because as far as I understand, I already added the <query> tag and it seemed to be either one or the other. I'll try tho

Comment: I tried it, and it results in the same error "Unable to start service Intent". Also, I'm checking on an Android 6device, but building with SDK 30

Comment: Use `adb` to list all the intent on your device, and check if you can find yours:
`adb shell dumpsys activity broadcasts |grep -iE ".+\.[0-9A-Z_\-]+:$" |sort`

Comment: Thanks ! I Just tried the command line and I don't see mine listed. Probably because I does not register it correctly. But I don't know why tho... :/

Answer (score 0):

You can declare permission in the app with service and use this permission in the app when you start intent

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).